# Assert Failure at application start: ReflectionTypeLoad_LoadFailed

Tags: catel

When I start the application, sometimes (mostly first time after compiling), the following error is displayed.
A restart of the application solves the problem most times.
How can I find out the root cause?

Besides the error message and the stack trace I have no other informations about the cause.
Visual Studio tells me the source informations for debugging are not available.
From the threads info window I cann see the main thread is in Catel.Reflection.ReflectionExtensions.GetTypesEx().

**ApplicationName.vshost.exe - Assert Failure**
**Expression:** [mscorlib recursive resource lookup bug]
**Description:** Infinite recursion during resource lookup within mscorlib.
This may be a bug in mscorlib, or potentially in certain extensibility points such as assembly resolve events or CultureInfo names.
**Resource name:** ReflectionTypeLoad_LoadFailed

The complete stack trace is available [in my onedrive](https://onedrive.live.com/embed?cid=D5B88A3595D43735&resid=D5B88A3595D43735%211721&authkey=AH45LnWU41avxvI).
Here are the first few lines:

```
Stack Trace:
at System.Environment.ResourceHelper.GetResourceStringCode(Object userDataln)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.ExecuteCodeWithGuaranteedCleanup(TryCode code, CleanupCode backoutCode, Object userData)
at System.Environment.ResourceHelper.GetResourceString(String key, CultureInfo culture)
at System.Environment.ResourceHelper.GetResourceString(String key)
at System.Environment.GetResourceStringLocal(String key)
at System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.GetTypes(RuntimeModule module)
at System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.GetTypes()
at System.ReflectionAssembly.GetTypes()
at Catel.Reflection.ReflectionExtensions.GetTypesEx(Assembly assembly) in c:\CIWSMA1596\Source\Catel\sraCatel.Core\Catel.CoreShareaReflection\Extensions\ReflectionExtensions.assembly.cs:line 33
at Catel.Reflection.AssemblyHelper.GetAllTypesSafely(Assembly assembly, Boolean logLoaderExceptions) in cACI_WS\WA1596\Source\Catel sraCatel.Core\Catel.Core.ShareaReflection\Helpers `, AssemblyHelper.cs:line 192
at Catel.Reflection.TypeCachelnitializeAssemblies(lEnumerablel assemblies) in cACI_WSWW\1596\Source\Catel\src\Catel.CoreKatel.Core.ShareaReflection\TypeCache.cs:line 583
at Catel.Reflection.TypeCachelnitializeTypes(Boolean forceFulllnitialization, Assembly assembly) in cACI_WSNWs\1596\Source\cateNsraCatel.Core\Catel.Core.ShareaReflection\TypeCache.cs:line 553
at Catel.Reflection.TypeCache.OnAssemblyLoaded(Object sender, AssemblyLoadEventArgs args) in c:\CI_WSNWs\1596\SourceKateNsraCatel.Core\Catel.Core.ShareaReflection\TypeCache.cs:line 131
at System.AssemblyLoadEventHandlerinvoke(Object sender, AssemblyLoadEventArgs args)
at SystemAppDomain.OnAssemblyLoadEvent(RuntimeAssembly LoadedAssembly)
at System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.GetTypes(RuntimeModule module)
at System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.GetTypes()
at System.Reflection.Assembly.GetTypes()
at Catel.Reflection.ReflectionExtensions.GetTypesEx(Assembly assembly) in c:\CIWS\Ws\1596\Source\Catel\src\Catel.Core\Catel.Core.Shared\Reflection\Extensions\ReflectionExtensions.assembly.cs:line 33
at Catel.ReflectionAssemblyHelper.GetAllTypesSafely(Assembly assembly, Boolean logLoaderExceptions) in c:\CI_WSNWs\1596\Source\catel\sraCatel.Core\Catel.Core.ShareaReflection\Helpers‘AssemblyHelper.cs:line 192
at Catel.Reflection.TypeCachelnitializeAssemblies(lEnumerablel assemblies) in cACI_WSNWs\1596\SourceKatel\src\Catel.Core\Catel.Core.ShareaReflection TypeCache.cs:line 583
at Catel.Reflection.TypeCachelnitializeTypes(Boolean forceFulllnitialization, Assembly assembly) in c:\CIWS\Ws\1596\Source\Catel\sraCatel.Core\Catel.Core.ShareaReflection\TypeCache.cs:line 553
at Catel.Reflection.TypeCache.OnAssemblyLoaded(Object sender, AssemblyLoadEventArgs args) in c:\CI__WS\WA1596\Source\Catel\sraCatel.Core\Catel.Core.ShareaReflection\TypeCache.cs:line 131
at System.AssemblyLoadEventHandlerinvoke(Object sender, AssemblyLoadEventArgs args)
at System.AppDomain.OnAssemblyLoadEvent(RuntimeAssembly LoadedAssembly)
at System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.GetTypes(RuntimeModule module)
at System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.GetTypes()
at System.Reflection.Assembly.GetTypes()
at Catel.Reflection.ReflectionExtensions.GetTypesEx(Assembly assembly) in c: CIWSNWs\1596\Source\Catel\src Catel.Core\Catel.Core.ShareaReflection Extensions\ReflectionExtensions.assembly.cs:line 33
at Catel.Reflection.AssemblyHelper.GetAllTypesSafely(Assembly assembly, Boolean logLoaderExceptions) in c:\CI_WSNWs\1596\Source\Catel sraCatel.Core\Catel.Core.ShareaReflection\Helpers\AssemblyHelper.cs:line 192
at Catel.Reflection.TypeCacheinitializeAssemblies(lEnumerablel assemblies) in cACI_WS\WA1596\Source\Catel\src\Catel.CoreKatel.Core.ShareaReflection\TypeCache.cs:line 583
at Catel.Reflection.TypeCacheinitializeTypes(Boolean forceFulllnitialization, Assembly assembly) in cACIWS\WA1596\Source\Catel\sraCatel.Core\Catel.Core.ShareaReflection‘TypeCache.cs:line 553
at Catel.Reflection.TypeCache.OnAssemblyLoaded(Object sender, AssemblyLoadEventArgs args) in c:\CI__WS\Ws\1596\Source\Catel\sraCatel.Core\Catel.Core.ShareaReflection‘TypeCache.cs:line 131
at System.AssemblyLoadEventHandlerinvoke(Object sender, AssemblyLoadEventArgs args)
at System.AppDomain.OnAssemblyLoadEvent(RuntimeAssembly LoadedAssembly)
```

Answer (score 0):

The AssemblyHelper in Catel creates a cache to make reflection as fast as possible. This means that it sometimes tries to load types / assemblies that cannot be loaded, but these are first-chance exceptions so can be safely ignored.

Comment: Unfortunately I have no chance to ignore this exception. It is shown in a modal popup dialog very different to other exceptions. Not even the concrete exception type is shown. So how and where could I ignore it? Shouldn't catel do this anyway?

Comment: Please provide repro at official issue tracker, see http://www.catelproject.com/support/issue-tracker